# How to bottom middle align a legend in Vega Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

In Vega Lite, I am trying to align my legend to the middle of this chart. I need something like an `anchor` parameter for the legend, but I can only find `titleAnchor`.

[Chart with Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETiFs.png)

```
"legend": {
        "title": "Signed NDA",
        "orient": "bottom",
        "titleAnchor": "middle"
      }
```

This is how my legend looks right now. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

This is actually possible within Vega 5.0, [legend layout property](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/config/#legend-layout-properties-50), by setting the `anchor` property to `"middle"`, in the legend's layout config.

Providing `layout` doesn't seem to be directly supported by Vega-Lite yet, but it is possible to propagate a `layout` definition from Vega-Lite to Vega.
Following Jake's answer, in [Vega-Lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegMYWQGcA6AK0IHsA7EAXwBoQBbAgawwAcKBLKqERgFMquCmF4BzeKAAe0kADNug1GAwAJCkUFcA7oOQCQUAJ4dBGAI6IIfbjCjcAbhYYgT8pSrVwQAWW5UQUIAfXNkEIBxCFRUaiNTcysbOwdnV0ZROMMERWVVDAB5ZG4JXgSzC18qCiZeGLo3AAtBUqb+OABmAAZuxl1uMCgm+AAWXszqJSlcoIlhH1AtZT4MACMKKChao1QIEwpEDtANrZ3c21wmrQw6sDAgxtpnoA):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "height": 300,
  "width": 400,
  
  "config": {
    "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}}
  }
}
```

Specifying the `config` at the end basically allows you to customize how the `orient` `"bottom"` should look.

[image]

Comment: Note: some as of you may find, "react-vega" does not like the typings in Typescript.  As such, I had to cast the code as follows

`layout: { bottom: { anchor: "middle" } } as LegendLayout as any,`

just in-case people wander here with Typescript/React in mind

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to anchor the legend in the bottom center, but you can set `orient: "none"` and use the `legendX` and `legendY` properties to locate it exactly where you would like. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegMYWQGcA6AK0IHsA7EAXwBoQBbAgawwAcKBLKqERgFMquCmF4BzeKAAe0kADNug1GAwAJCkUFcA7oOQCQUAJ4dBGAI6IIfbjCjcAbhYYgT8pSrVwQAWW5UQUIAfXNkEIBxCFRUaiNTcysbOwdnV0ZROMMERWVVDAB5ZG4JXgSzC18qCiZeGKMgiWEfUC1lPgwaqgtGcWRBXEd43wALdoAvahh0RiaWgA14AEYAJgAGOcFmqjAATXgAZgAWTeN7IPgqRFjaO8ZRwVLR-jhD9bPdbjAoUfhT9a0IA)):

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "Origin",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {
        "orient": "none",
        "direction": "horizontal",
        "legendX": 120,
        "legendY": 340,
        "title": null
      }
    }
  },
  "height": 300,
  "width": 400
}
```

[image]