# Position altair legend top-center

Tags: altair

I would like to position an `altair` legend top-center. Getting it to the top is simple enough by passing `legend=alt.Legend(title=None, orient="top")`. I also gather that [this is possible in `vega-lite`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702702/1291563) but am having trouble making that all work together.
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Altair does not yet support the `layout` property that newer versions of Vega-Lite support, but you can position your legend manually following the approach used in one of the other answers to the linked question.

For example:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color=alt.Color('Origin', legend=alt.Legend(
        orient='none',
        legendX=130, legendY=-40,
        direction='horizontal',
        titleAnchor='middle'))
)
```

[image]